# How to escape especial character like < > on Aspose.PDF using CSHTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, aspose

I keep getting error on these ( < > ) characters. the app that my company uses is written in asp.Net MVC I handle the configuration CSHTML part of this app. to my understanding this app takes all the quires and runs against the database (sql) then using CHSTML to display the result on PDF format. The error occurs in one column that has characters < >. 
I'm not allowed to edit the data. Is there a way That I can escape this in CSHTML. 
this is an example of the line code in cshtml configuration

```
@Html.Raw(headerRowHelper.FormatData(null, " Description ", null, true))
@foreach (DataRow row in TabData_7.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    `@Html.Raw(dataRowHelper2.FormatData(null, row["SEGMENTDESC"], null, true))`
}
```

Comment: anyone have an idea I tried to use @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(dataRowHelper2.FormatData(null, row["SEGMENTDESC"], null, true))). This did not thru an error also it did not display anything in the result.

Comment: Can you please elaborate if you are facing a problem while working with any feature of Aspose.Pdf, or not? PS: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Yes, the cshtml file using Aspose.pdf. I need to know how to escape those characters < >

Comment: Kindly share a narrowed down code snippet, along with the source file, if any, and the steps to reproduce this issue with Aspose.Pdf so that we may investigate it further to help you out.

Comment: Thank you i got it fixed by adding this piece of code @Html.Raw(dataRowHelper2.FormatData(null, Html.Encode(row["SEGMENTDESC"]), null, true))

Comment: We are glad to know that your issue is resolved. In case you face any problem while working with Aspose APIs then feel free to contact us. We will be pleased to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

By Adding this line of code it did the job.

```
@Html.Raw(dataRowHelper2.FormatData(null, Html.Encode(row["SEGMENTDESC"]), null, true))
```